# passing dynamic array of structure to fun in c/c++

Tags: c, data-structures, structure, dynamic-arrays

I have this assignment https://i.stack.imgur.com/fel89.png
to create a **dynamic array of structure then send to two functions**, one to ask the user to enter values and the author to print these values. with **c** or **c++**.
I tried with c but it shows errors, can you help me, please.
Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Employee {
    int Id;
    char Name;
    int Degree;
    int Age;
}

void inputFun(struct Employee * EmpArr, int empNum);
void printFun(struct Employee * EmpArr, int empNum);

int main()
{
    int empNum;
    printf("Hello, Specify the Number of Employees Please");
    scanf("%d", &empNum);
    
    struct Employee * MyEmpArr = malloc(empNum*sizeof(struct Employee)); //array of structure
    
    inputFun(MyEmpArr, empNum);
    
    printf("\n");
    
    printFun(MyEmpArr, empNum);
    
    return 0;
}
void inputFun(struct Employee * EmpArr, int empNum){
   for(int i = 0; i < empNum; i++ ){
        printf("\nEnter details of Employee %d\n\n", i+1);

        printf("Id: ");
        scanf("%d", &EmpArr[i].Id);

        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%c", &EmpArr[i].Name);

        printf("Degree: ");
        scanf("%d", &EmpArr[i].Degree);
        
        printf("Age: ");
        scanf("%d", &EmpArr[i].Age);
    }
}
void printFun(struct Employee * EmpArr, int empNum){
    printf("Employee details are: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < empNum; i++ )
        printf("%d\t%c\t%d\t%d\n", EmpArr[i].Id, EmpArr[i].Name, EmpArr[i].Degree, EmpArr[i].Age);
}
```

Comment: you were asked to solve it with c or c++, you chose c, so this question is about c. There is no language called C/C++

Comment: A semicolon is required after structure declaration. Vote to close for typo or search for duplicate?

Comment: When posting questions about errors, please include the full and complete error output, copy-pasted as text. Also please add comments in the shown code where you get the errors. Please take some time to take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) to learn how to write good questions.

Comment: Two things: you're missing a semi-colon after struct declaration (as pointed out by @MikeCAT) and you never freed the malloc-ed memory, thereby leaking memory. After the printFun() call, use ` free(MyEmpArr);`